# Accidentally removed my entire taskbar. How do I get it back? (Kubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu

Ok. I somehow ended up with a Chromium icon right beside ...whatever Kubuntu calls the Start button on taskbar on the bottom. In trying to remove that, the entire thing is now gone and pressing the windows key on the keyboard no longer brings up the app launcher thing.

Answer (score 2):

right click desktop and add panel?